# Access textboxes dynamically created at runtime

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I add textboxes dynamically at runtime. How do I access them later in the program?

Answer (score 5):

First name the dynamically created control

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim MyTextBox As New TextBox
    MyTextBox.Name = "MyTextBox"
    Me.Controls.Add(MyTextBox)
end sub
```

Somewhere else in the program:

```
    'set text
    Me.Controls("MyTextBox").Text = "Hi there"
    'fetch text
    Dim thetext = Me.Controls("MyTextBox").Text

    'fetch textbox
    Dim tb As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls("MyTextBox"), TextBox)
    tb.Text = ""
    tb.BackColor = Color.Red
```

Another way is to loop through the me.controlls-collection and find the control that way (maybe you have set .tag="mycontrol" on those or something else...

Comment: Its possible to use "me.dynamicpanel.Controls("MyTextBox").Text" if the textbox was created inside a panel also created dynamically?